Getting error, WebSocket connection to 'wss://website.azurewebsites.net:8080/ws' failed: When making POST Request from React to Azure SQL server
I am having a problem with my azure web app (linux) while trying to add data into my sql database
Here are the errors im getting:
DataAdd.js:26 
POST https://website.azurewebsites.net:5000/add-data net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at handleSubmit (DataAdd.js:26:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1

WebSocketClient.js:13 WebSocket connection to 'wss://website.azurewebsites.net:8080/ws' failed:

Here is my DataAdd.js code:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './DataAdd.css';

const DataAdd = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    description: '',
    Nimi: '',
    Syntymäaika: '',
    Rotu: '',
    Sukupuoli: '',
    Rekisterinumero: '',
    Omistaja: ''
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await fetch('https://website.azurewebsites.net:5000/add-data', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
      });
      if (response.ok) {
        alert('Data added successfully');
        setFormData({
          description: '',
          Nimi: '',
          Syntymäaika: '',
          Rotu: '',
          Sukupuoli: '',
          Rekisterinumero: '',
          Omistaja: ''
        });
      } else {
        alert('Error adding data');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      alert('Error adding data');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Data</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="description" value={formData.description} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Nimi</label>
          <input type="text" name="Nimi" value={formData.Nimi} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Syntymäaika</label>
          <input type="date" name="Syntymäaika" value={formData.Syntymäaika} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Rotu</label>
          <input type="text" name="Rotu" value={formData.Rotu} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Sukupuoli</label>
          <input type="text" name="Sukupuoli" value={formData.Sukupuoli} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Rekisterinumero</label>
          <input type="text" name="Rekisterinumero" value={formData.Rekisterinumero} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Omistaja</label>
          <input type="text" name="Omistaja" value={formData.Omistaja} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add Data</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataAdd;

Here is my server.js code:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const sql = require('mssql');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SERVER_PORT;

const config = {
    user: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_USER,
    password: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD,
    server: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_SERVER,
    port: parseInt(process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_PORT, 10),
    database: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_DATABASE,
    authentication: {
        type: 'default'
    },
    options: {
        encrypt: true,
        requestTimeout: 60000,
        connectionTimeout: 30000
    }
};

// Add CORS middleware
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'https://website.azurewebsites.net', // Adjust based on your frontend URL
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}));

// Add body parser middleware
app.use(express.json());

async function connectWithRetry() {
    let retries = 5;
    while (retries) {
        try {
            const pool = await sql.connect(config);
            return pool;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(`Connection failed, retries left: ${retries - 1}`);
            console.error(err);
            retries -= 1;
            await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000)); // wait for 5 seconds before retrying
        }
    }
    throw new Error('Could not connect to the database after multiple attempts');
}

connectWithRetry().then(pool => {
    console.log("Connected to the database");

    app.post('/add-data', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            console.log('Received request:', req.body);
            const { description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja } = req.body;

            console.log('Connecting to database...');
            const result = await pool.request()
                .input('description', sql.NVarChar, description)
                .input('Nimi', sql.NVarChar, Nimi)
                .input('Syntymäaika', sql.Date, Syntymäaika)
                .input('Rotu', sql.NVarChar, Rotu)
                .input('Sukupuoli', sql.NVarChar, Sukupuoli)
                .input('Rekisterinumero', sql.NVarChar, Rekisterinumero)
                .input('Omistaja', sql.NVarChar, Omistaja)
                .query(`
                    INSERT INTO dbo.hevoset (description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja)
                    VALUES (@description, @Nimi, @Syntymäaika, @Rotu, @Sukupuoli, @Rekisterinumero, @Omistaja)
                `);

            console.log('Data added:', result);
            res.status(200).send('Data added successfully');
        } catch (err) {
            console.error('Error adding data:', err);
            res.status(500).send('Error adding data');
        }
    });

    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
    });
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Database connection failed: ', err.message);
});

What I have tried:
Verified server is running: Server is running and logs indicate it is listening on the correct port.
Checked URL and port: Ensured that the URL and port in the React fetch call match the server's URL and port.
Configured CORS: Set CORS options to allow requests from the client URL.
Tested endpoint with curl/Postman: Direct requests to the server endpoint from curl/Postman work without issues.
Tested it on local, connection to the database works and so does adding data.
Added logging: Added logging to capture incoming requests and errors.
What I expect:
I expect the POST request from my React application to successfully reach the SQL Server, allowing data to be added to the Azure SQL database.
Environment:
Client: React web app hosted on Azure (Linux)
Server: SQL server hosted on Azure
Database: SQL database on Azure

are you using azure mysql server /azure sql server

if you are using azure my sql the connection should be like this var conn=mysql.createConnection({host:"AzureSqlServerName.mysql.database.azure.com", user:"UserName", password:"{your_password}", database:"{your_database}", port:3306, ssl:{ca:fs.readFileSync("{ca-cert filename}")}});

Yes im using azure mysql server

Connection to the database works, i get the console log connected to the database.

change the connection parameters to                                                                        host: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_SERVER, // e.g., "AzureSqlServerName.mysql.database.azure.com"     user: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_USER, // e.g., "UserName"     password: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_PASSWORD, // e.g., "your_password"     database: process.env.REACT_APP_AZURE_SQL_DATABASE, // e.g., "your_database"     port: 3306,     ssl: {         rejectUnauthorized: true // Enable SSL connection     }

add axios  in react app in this example here and Connect, create table, and insert data in MySQL connector

I even tried to run your code but I get a WSS and CORS error, shown the same null data in adding. Then change your code as follows: the server-side logic stored in the backend code where we interact with db,api end points and process data.
I configured CORS to allow requests from all urls to the backend as shown here:
app.use(cors({
  origin: '*', 
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}));

Change the INSERT query like this to avoid null:
INSERT INTO hevoset (description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

Backend:
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const fs = require('fs');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001;

const config = {
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER ,
  password:  process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: process.env.DB_NAME,
  port: 3306,
  ssl: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync("DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt.pem")
  }
};

const conn = mysql.createConnection(config);

app.use(cors({
  origin: '*', 
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204
}));
app.use(express.json());

async function connectWithRetry() {
  let retries = 5;
  while (retries) {
    try {
      conn.connect(err => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log("Connected to the database");
        }
      });
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`Connection failed, retries left: ${retries - 1}`);
      console.error(err);
      retries -= 1;
      await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 5000)); 
    }
  }
  throw new Error('Could not connect to the database after multiple attempts');
}

connectWithRetry().catch(err => {
  console.error('Database connection failed: ', err.message);
});

app.post('/add-data', (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('Received request:', req.body);
    const { description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja } = req.body;

    const sql = `
      INSERT INTO hevoset (description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja)
      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    `;

    conn.query(sql, [description, Nimi, Syntymäaika, Rotu, Sukupuoli, Rekisterinumero, Omistaja], (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error('Error adding data:', err);
        res.status(500).send('Error adding data');
      } else {
        console.log('Data added:', results);
        res.status(200).send('Data added successfully');
      }
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error adding data:', err);
    res.status(500).send('Error adding data');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`);
});

The frontend code handles the user interface and user interactions for backend. I used axios to connect backend as shown here:
const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8001/add-data', formData);

Frontend:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import './DataAdd.css';

const DataAdd = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    description: '',
    Nimi: '',
    Syntymäaika: '',
    Rotu: '',
    Sukupuoli: '',
    Rekisterinumero: '',
    Omistaja: ''
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormData({
      ...formData,
      [name]: value
    });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8001/add-data', formData);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        alert('Data added successfully');
        setFormData({
          description: '',
          Nimi: '',
          Syntymäaika: '',
          Rotu: '',
          Sukupuoli: '',
          Rekisterinumero: '',
          Omistaja: ''
        });
      } else {
        alert('Error adding data');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
      alert('Error adding data');
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add Data</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>Description</label>
          <input type="text" name="description" value={formData.description} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Nimi</label>
          <input type="text" name="Nimi" value={formData.Nimi} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Syntymäaika</label>
          <input type="date" name="Syntymäaika" value={formData.Syntymäaika} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Rotu</label>
          <input type="text" name="Rotu" value={formData.Rotu} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Sukupuoli</label>
          <input type="text" name="Sukupuoli" value={formData.Sukupuoli} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Rekisterinumero</label>
          <input type="text" name="Rekisterinumero" value={formData.Rekisterinumero} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label>Omistaja</label>
          <input type="text" name="Omistaja" value={formData.Omistaja} onChange={handleChange} required />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add Data</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataAdd;



